# How to catch http errors in angular(ionic)?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm trying to catch HTTP error with error code 400 using the following code in a ionic4 application. But it fails to catch it, what's wrong in here. None of the console log lines executes, but in firefox console it shows 400 error.

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)  {}

  login(email: string, password: string){

    const data = {
      password: password,
      email: email,
    }

    this.httpClient.post(url, data).pipe(
      tap((res: IAuthResponse) => {
        console.log("Catch error 1") 
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log("Catch error 2")
        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
      })
    ).subscribe( 
       (result) => {
         console.log("Catch error 3")
       },
       (error) => {
          console.log("Catch error 4")
       }
    );
  }
```

[image]

Actually i just want to handle this error in any of the place where i coded console.log line. Found many examples like this, but none of them works.

**Edit** : In my real code this, console log line 1 is in the AuthService class but the subscribe code is in a different class file. Both these classes has to do some initialization based on the results. So I need to have both of pipe code and subscribe code.

Answer (score 7):

this is the way that can be done

> Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weg6u6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
this.httpClient.post("ssdsdsd", data).pipe(
      (res: any) => {
        console.log("Catch res ") 
        return res;
      },
    ).subscribe( 
       (result) => {
         console.log("Catch result ")
       },
       (error) => {
          console.log("Catch error ")
       }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `pipe` in `httpClient`
You can try like this:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, data).subscribe((res: any) => {
}, (error) => {
  console.log("Catch error ")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think my question is not detail enough. In my real code this, console log line 1 is in the AuthService class but the subscribe code is in a different class file. Both these classes has to do some initialization based on the results.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is `The Catch and Rethrow Strategy`, as explained [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) in details. Its pretty straightward implementation, no matter if your `pipe-catchError` & `subscription` exists in same class or different, I can't think of a reason why your code is acting weird. I would say put debug points in your code and debug in chrome/firefox developer mode.

```
const http$ = this.http.get<Course[]>('/api/courses');

http$
    .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
            return throwError(err);
        })
    )
    .subscribe(
        res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
        err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
        () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sameera.. you can catch the error (with status code) something like below,

```
this.httpClient.post(url, data, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe((res: IAuthResponse) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
   }, fail => {
          console.log(fail.status);
       }
   );
```

you don't need to use any pipe or other operators for this..

you can check more about this here **[`httpClient response with Status code`](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)**. hope this helps..  :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think my question is not detail enough. In my real code this, console log line 1 is in the AuthService class but the subscribe code is in a different class file. Both these classes has to do some initialization based on the results